# INSERT INTO - write results of VBA variable into a table

Tags: ms-access, sql-insert

I have a login form that the user completes and when the Login in button is pressed, it writes the values into a table called tblLoginUsers. I also have code that looks up the user from another table called tblUsers and checks to see what Role is assigned to the user. The code in the form (frmLogin) is correctly looking up the value (I checked in the debug process), but I just cannot get the variable to write the result into the Role field in the tblLoginUsers

My intention is to check the user role and then open the relevant ribbon accessible to the user.

This is the code. There are no error messages, and the table is not updated with the role.

```vb
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click() 
    Dim strUser As String 
    Dim strRole As String 
    Dim strSQL As String 
    Dim db As DAO.Database 
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset 
 
    ' Get the user ID entered in the textbox 
    strUser = Me.txtUser.Value 
 
    ' Build SQL to retrieve the role for the user 
    strSQL = "SELECT Role FROM tblUsers WHERE UserId='" & strUser & "';" 
 
    ' Open a recordset based on the SQL query 
    Set db = CurrentDb 
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL) 
 
    ' Check if a record was found 
    If Not rs.EOF Then 
        ' Retrieve the value of the Role field 
        strRole = rs("Role") 
 
        ' Insert the Role value into the tblUserLogin table 
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUserLogin (Role) VALUES ('" & strRole & "');" 
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL 
'        db.Execute strSQL 
        rs.Requery 
        ' Close the recordset 
        rs.Close 
    Else 
        ' No matching user found 
        MsgBox "Invalid user ID", vbExclamation 
    End If 
 
    ' Clean up objects 
    Set rs = Nothing 
    Set db = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't insert an empty user, so try:

```
' Insert the Role value into the tblUserLogin table 
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUserLogin (UserID, Role) VALUES ('" & strUserID & "','" & strRole & "');"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with my original design was that the user login form was adding details to the current record. I was then attempting to look up the `role` value from another table and insert it as a new record instead of updating the existing one.

Subsequently, I made the form's text boxes unbound and used the `strSQL` string to insert a new record with the values from the two text boxes and the looked-up variable.